# Low amplitude curent measurement

Tags: current, measurement, meter

Can someone from their experience share part number for equipment for low current measurement. The current to be measured is less than 6nA.
I am aware that I can connect a resistor and by measuring the voltage drop across the resistor, I can calculate the current.
Is there any equipment in the market which can measure such low current?

Awaiting for your kind reply!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can buy a multimeter that can measure 6nA. For example, the 7.5 digit 34470A has a 1uA full-scale DC current range, accuracy in the 50pA neighborhood. It's a nice piece of kit, but a bit expensive.

For cheap measurement you can use a common handheld multimeter if you know the input resistance. For example, the +/-199.9mV range on a 3.5 digit multimeter with 10M\$\Omega\$ input resistance acts as a DC ammeter with a full scale range of 19.99nA.

If you want to make a circuit, a useful part (perhaps gross overkill) is the [LMC6001](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmc6001.pdf?HQS=TI-null-null-digikeymode-df-pf-null-wwe&ts=1596033820894), which has a guaranteed input bias current at room temperature of less than 25fA (10fA typical), which is ~0.0004% (~0.0002% typical) of the current you want to measure. That and a resistor will do it. Of course you need to take extreme measures to get full performance out of that op-amp, but 6nA is actually a pretty heavy current. Avoid conductive fluxes and keep things very clean.

Answer (score 0):

6nA is an extremely low current to measure !! It is very close to noise in a typicla circuit and you will need alot of gain to and conversion to a voltage to measure this level ... It is beyond the competence of a single, readily available semiconductor device to do this. More like a highly sensitive dedicated instrument. Look at Fluke or Agilent etc for such equipment ... good luck

Comment: 6nA, not hardly, many opamps measure 1pA